# Trying to merge multiple lines in the console to an array

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

I am getting a json feed and i'm trying to get the values out of it and set it to an array.

This is what i get inside the console:

[Console Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1GI1u.png)

This is my code:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var allData, exampleallData;

    allData = {
        'action': 'ajax'
    };  

    jQuery.get(ajaxurl, allData, function(response) {
        exampleallData = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
        jQuery.each(exampleallData, function(index, value) {
            if(value.meta_key === 'brand') {
                console.log(value.meta_value);
            }
        });

    });
});
```

Hopefully someone can tell me why it's breaking on new lines in the console and what the solution is for it with explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because using this:

```
jQuery.each(exampleallData, function(index, value) {
        if(value.meta_key === 'brand') {
            console.log(value.meta_value);
        }
    });
```

You are calling **console.log** for each element of **exampleallData**.

The solution for this should be creating a new empty array, then adding each element to that array and finally console.log the new array.

It should be something like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
var allData, exampleallData;

allData = {
    'action': 'ajax'
};  

jQuery.get(ajaxurl, allData, function(response) {
    var newArray = [];
    exampleallData = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
    jQuery.each(exampleallData, function(index, value) {
        if(value.meta_key === 'brand') {
            newArray.push(value.meta_value);
        }
    });
    console.log(newArray);

});
});
```